# Display all object, filter on a property if it exists in AnguarJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is this:

I have a course list that populates by making an API call and displays a list of results. You can filter each course by subject, or by keyword.

One set of courses belongs has an attribute called "Path" that not all courses will have.

In the API, I can assign a value of 1, 2, 3, 4, or Null to the value "Path". Below is the code that allows me to filter over the courses with a Path property.

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="course in ds.courseList | unique:'course_path'">
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ds.searchPath" ng-true-value="{$course.course_path$}" ng-false-value="">{$course.course_path$}</label>
</div>
```

So the real problem is that AngularJS is picking up the Null value and displaying it as a checkbox with no label, or (with a minor tweak) not displaying any course unless it has a path property.

How can I display all courses, regardless of whether they have a path property of 1, 2, 3,4 or Null, and not have Angular display the empty checkbox?

EDITED FOR CLARITY: All of the courses have multiple properties and there are three search fields: keyword (which search the title), subject, and Path. In the Path search, there is a list of checkboxes generated by AngularJS which displays a checkbox for each unique value in Path; 1, 2, 3, 4 or Null. THe problem I am having is that everything I've done to hide the Null value, also filters out all of the courses in the list that have a Null path value. I just want to filter on Path if Path != null.

TL;DR: I want to hide checkbox with the value of Null, without hiding the course with the Path value of Null from course list.

Comment: I don't get it. If there is no path what would be displayed?

Comment: THat's the problem, if the object has a null path value, nothing is displayed, and it should be. All objects have a path value of 1, 2, 3, 4, or Null. That generates a series of checkboxes with values of 1, 2, 3, 4, or Blank. How do I remove or hide the empty checkbox?

Comment: Are you trying something like this- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKpJxV

Comment: @NagaSaiA Almost ... I'd like all of the courses to display including the ones without a Path property. What I'm trying to do is form a conditional statement that hides the checkbox if the value is empty or null, and displays the checkboxes if the values are 1, 2, 3, or 4 --- but at the same time, doesn't hide all of the courses from the list.

Comment: are you looking for something like this -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKpJxV

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-if` to not include checkbox without path

```
<div class="checkbox" 
     ng-repeat="course in ds.courseList | unique:'course_path'"
     ng-if="course.course_path">
```

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work. Create a demo in plunker with some sample data

Comment: It hides all of the courses that don't have a path. I need all of the courses to display whether the path is 1 2, 3, 4 or Null, and only hide the checkbox generated by the NG-repeat when the value is null -- without hiding all of the courses with a null path value.

Comment: But what would be displayed? Your label is the path. In one place you say remove checkbox in another you say show it. Very confusing

Comment: Yes, that's confusing. If you want to hide the checkbox `ng-if` should work and for the label you could add a default value with `|| 'no path'`. Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/nffddcsw/). (Note: `ng-if` won't work as expected if your null is of type String `'null'`. Then a comparison inside the if could help.)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="course in courseList ">
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ds.searchPath" ng-show="{{course['course_path']}}">{{course['course_path']}}</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKpJxV

Comment: in your case use ng-show="{{$course.course_path$}}"

Comment: Don't use `{{}}` in ng-show. it evaluates expressions directly

Comment: yes @charlieftl , Kickasstimus use ng-show="$course.course_path$"

Comment: are you trying to display all courses and all course paths with paths-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKpJxV

Comment: any luck @Kickasstimus ??

Comment: Decided to just limit the list with LimitTo: -4